# 20.04 / Gnome: How to reset all configurations of a user

Tags: nvidia, gnome, upgrade, 20.04, users

I have been running Ubuntu for years now with only LTS upgrades. root and /home are separate partitions so I have always kept /home and that served me fine until now. There is only the one user, myself.
Since the upgrade to 20.04, there are multiple issues with this user though. Sleep mode is wonky and unreliable, the NVIDIA graphics driver can't be installed since a kernel update, some audio settings don't last beyond a restart. When I create another user, then everything works just fine over there. I strongly suspect that some old config files from way back when are causing me issues, especially since Snaps are a thing.

Now, I could of course delete everything, create a whole new user for myself and then play everything back from a backup, which would take hours.

Or is there a way to 'rejuvenate' the user settings so that it acts like a fresh system, except my personal files are still there? I have found a way to reset Gnome but apparently the issue lies deeper than that.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: How many upgrades have you done on this machine? The first version was ? and now on 20.04.

Comment: You could do something like `diff --recursive /home/newuser /home /tom`.

Comment: See the question I marked as duplicate. It indicates how to "reset" your account. You can then quickly move your user data back from the renamed, original account.

Comment: Hello David! I have done many upgrades, I  can find folders from 2008.
Waltinator - I will try that! Thanks!
Vanadium - unfortunately not as backing up, then copying back a huge amount of data is what I am trying to avoid. But thank you very much for the suggestion as I may have to come4 back to that if all else fails.